# Rules with condition on taxonomy

Tags: 8, rules

Im doing a simple Rules that when a content is created of type X, and has taxonomy term of T1, simple action to display a message in the page.

> **Events**: After saving new content (rules_entity_insert:node)
>
> **Conditions**:
>
> - Node is of type
> - ***How to configure this item to select taxonomy term???***
>
> **Action**: Show a message on the site

Comment: I realize this is a D8 question, but it might help if you edit your question to explain how you would do this with rules in D7 ... eg by including an export (or screenprint using the Rules UI) in your question.

Comment: Yes, I added tag to determine its in D8. Honestly I dont see any documentation in the web how to configure taxonomy term as condition in D8. As mentioned in the question, its just as easy as "if content has taxonomy term of T1". I believe this is an easy option for D7. Im not really good at creating custom rules but if this simple approach is not configurable from the UI, then I think I will proceed to creating one.

Answer (score 0):

add one condition that checks if the node has field_term_ref (term reference) equal to what term name you wish for it.

1. Choose the action "Set a data value".
2. Choose the taxonomy term reference field to set.
3. "Switch to the direct input mode" button to reveal the terms available in your taxonomy field.

Comment: I would love to see something like an exported rule to demonstrate a ***working*** sample of this. Please edit your answer to include such rule ...

Comment: @alexb: Thanks for your response, and it looks like a simple answer but not detailed. Yes please, can you break it down to include a rule?

Comment: I've added an list of steps, hope it helps